# Advanced pattern matching in Makefile

Tags: regex, makefile, gnu-make

Is it possible to create a Makefile pattern matching with two or three varying patterns? I'm using Gnu make.

In my current set-up, in simplified form, I'm using two Bash for-loops in order to convert a certain set of files to another set, and to create the final result file. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
XMIN=$1
XMAX=$2
YMIN=$3
YMAX=$4
z=$5
FINAL_LIST=
for y in `seq $YMIN $YMAX`;
do
  SOURCE_LIST=
  echo Processing column $y
  for x in `seq $XMIN $XMAX`;
    do
    # Convert from file source/something_${x}_${y}_${z} to
    #    target/something_else_$${x}_${y}_${z}
    echo Processing X ${x} Y ${y} with Z ${z}
    # do_something
    SOURCE_LIST+="target/something_else_$${x}_${y}_${z} "
    done
  # Create something for this line
  echo Processing ${SOURCE_LIST} target_line_${y}_${z}
  # process the line
  FINAL_LIST+="target_line_${y}_${z} "
done
# Finally, compose the final thing
echo Process the final result: ${FINAL_LIST} result_${z}
# process the final result
# We're done
```

I would like to make this more effectively with Makefile, as it would allow me to execute things in parallel, and also it would take care, that "line results" are re-generated only when something changes for that particular line.

I'm already using Makefile to convert single datafiles to another format, with simple pattern matching. Makefile is very good in handling my base of >500k datafiles - it can very fast detect changed source files and execute the conversion only for the changed datafiles.

The problem here is that I don't know, how to make Makefile patterns with more than one varying pattern. Following is an easy pattern:

```
%.target : %.source
    # do something
```

But I don't know, whether the following would be possible (as pseudocode):

```
<var_pat_Z>_<var_pat_Y>.target: <var_pat_Z>_<var_pat_Y>.source
    # do something else
```

It is not necessary to implement this with Makefile, but I would still need to find a way to detect changed source files, and the capability to execute things in parallel. Currently I'm handling those detections in my bash scripts, and the parallelization by executing bash scripts in parallel with Gnu parallel command. Anyway, that is most likely not the optimal way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you have a bunch of `*.source` files, and want a rule that turns each into a `*.target` file, while picking two sub-strings from whatever the `*` expands to.

Why not pick the *stem* in `$*` apart at the underscore? Here's a solution.
If you have these files

```
$ ls *.source
1_1.source
1_2.source
1_3.source
a_b.source
foo_bar.source
```

then running this GNUmakefile's default target

```
# all should depend on all targets for which a source exists.
all: $(shell echo *.source | sed 's/source/target/g')

%.target: %.source
    @z="$*" y="$*"; \
    z=$${z%%_*} y=$${y##*_}; \
    echo z=$$z y=$$y
```

will give you

```
$ gmake
z=1 y=1
z=1 y=2
z=1 y=3
z=a y=b
z=foo y=bar
```

Comment: Very good, that you brought up the possibility to use shell command output in the dependency generation. This in fact brings solution to my problem. I was thinking this in bit too complicated way - it is enough, that I introduce the dynamics only into dependency lines. This way, I can separate those two loops into two separate Makefiles (inner and outer) and have both parallelism and tracking I need.